# Multiple instances of Atom (Portable Atom Mac-OS)

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I would like to find a way to run two instances of Atom with different configurations and in different windows.

1. In order to make that work I've grabbed Atom Beta version, and it runs in different windows (seems good atm).
2. Then I found config `~/.atom` folder on `OS X` and made a duplicate of it, but now I struggle now to make Atom Beta use that new folder, since by default it's binded to look in `~/.atom`.

Maybe someone knows the way how to end this task, or maybe similar effective approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the official atom documentation currently (5 March 2018) doesn't cover the approach for Mac OS X. The solution is discussed and explained [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/13426).

**Simple way:** 

1. Create folder ***portableAtom*** anywhere you want, it's where the portable version will be stored. 
2. Copy an instance of atom/atom beta application into the folder ***portableAtom***. 
3. Using terminal reveal hidden directories by executing `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

3.2 Holding 'alt' right click Finder and select `Relaunch`
3.1 Navigate to your directory (cmd+shift+H) in `Finder`.
3.2 Locate and copy `.atom` folder into the previously created folder ***portableAtom***

3.3 In terminal execute `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO`

3.4 Repeat action 3.2

4. Now you can use your *portable* version of Atom with separated configurations for each one.

**P.S**: The logic behind is that Atom will look for `.atom` configuration folder in the same directory where it *sits* if it doesn't it will look for a default folder in your Home directory.